# How to store an integer (such as a high score) so that it would save even after the program was closed?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game that saves a high score even after the program has stopped running so that, when I run it again, the high score will still be saved.

- For some reason, the pickle module doesn't work with the Python program I'm using, so I can't use that as a solution.
- I've tried saving the integers to .txt files as strings, but it always just prints out when I try to call it back and I can't figure out how to change the value after I call it back.

How could I do this?
This is what I've tried to do:

```
def savehighscore(x):
    with open('highscore.txt','w') as file:
        file.write(str(x))
def play():
    #Game code would go here and output a variable "highscore"
    highscore=10 #Example
    oldhighscore=open('highscore.txt')
    if highscore>int(oldhighscore):
        oldhighscore.close()
        with open('highscore.txt','w') as file:
            file.write(highscore)
savehighscore(5)
play()
```

It outputs a TypeError, saying that "oldhighscore" can't be converted to an integer.

Comment: Why pickle module doesn't work? Anyways you have to read and write the file again to save. In stackoverflow is better to post questions with code, your attempt. (I think your question will be downvoted)

Comment: You'll have to save the data in a file. Please [edit] your question and add the code for one (or both) of the solutions you have tried.

Comment: pickle is good option to save your python object . there are numerous options to store your higher score. save in json file its easy to call and update json values, first try to solve with pickle because that is best option

Comment: There are multiple questions in here, so let’s focus on a single one. You say you’ve tried writing them to file, _but it always just prints out when I try to call it back and I can’t figure out how to change the value after I call back._ What does that mean, exactly? Can you share some code ([mcve]), and gives us far more information?

Comment: There is no reason why pickle shouldn't work. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to open your text document, then read the first line into a variable.  Then use that variable for comparison and/or writing back out to the file you close then overwrite.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you!